# Создать окно заданного размера

Tags: python, tkinter

помогите пожалуйста исправить код

```
import tkinter

def makeWorkArea(parent):
    WorkArea = tkinter.Frame(parent)
    WorkArea.config(relief = 'sunken', width = 340, height = 170, bg = 'red')
    WorkArea.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

    msg = tkinter.Label(WorkArea, text='Window menu basics')
    msg.pack()

root = tkinter.Tk()
makeWorkArea(root)
root.mainloop()
```

проблема в том, что в параметрах упаковщика указаны конкретные размеры области WorkArea по вертикали и по горизонтали, но после запуска программы почему-то создаётся окно меньшего размера(примерно равного размеру надписи msg). можно ли сделать так чтобы после запуска создавалось окно размером 340x170 пикселей, залитое красным цветом. и в этом окне размещался текст msg ?

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin не так?

    def makeWorkArea(parent):
      msg = tkinter.Label(parent, text='Window menu basics', relief = 'sunken', width = 340, height = 170, bg = 'red')
      msg.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

Comment: так наверное не пойдёт. дело в том, что в виджет frame я кроме msg буду вкладывать и другие виджеты. и все они должны находиться в окне(области) размером 340x170 px

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin Неохота вспоминать особенности pack и place, поэтому может так?

    def makeWorkArea(parent):
      WorkArea = tkinter.Frame(parent)
      WorkArea.config(relief = 'sunken', width = 340, height = 170, bg = 'red')
      WorkArea.grid()

      msg = tkinter.Label(parent, text='Window menu basics', relief = 'sunken', bg = 'red')
      msg.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.E+tkinter.W)

А насчёт "все они" -- это со скроллингом?

Comment: да, со скроллингом.
спасибо кстати, ваше последнее решение работает. хотя при изменении размеров окна размер красной области не изменяется... вот так наверное нужно)
root.geometry("340x170")

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin не изменяется, потому что не просят. См. columnconfigure и rowconfigure, т.е. убираем конкретный размер, и добавляем вес колонке и ряду:


    WorkArea.grid(sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.E+tkinter.W+tkinter.S)
    parent.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    parent.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

Что касается скроллинга, https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=tkinter+frame+scrolling&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: ну спасибо. теперь я полностью вооружён)

Answer (score 2):

`root.geometry('800x600')` должен помочь.